# Ubuntu 12.10 - Problems with installing Nvidia Drivers

Tags: installation, 12.10, drivers, nvidia

I have some big problems with installing the latest Nvidia drivers on my  Ubuntu 12.10 at a Notebook.

2 weeks ago, I have tested the Ubuntu 12.04 and I got no problems with it. I have just downloaded the latest drivers, opened a shell stopped the server x and installed it.
Everything was fine.
But it isn't in the version 12.10. So I have checked out the net for some instructions and I have read that I must download kernel modules (header & sources) to install it.
So I have downloaded these packages, and tried it again. I was able to install the driver and so I rebooted the OS. After I lodged in, I couldn't see the 'Launcher' on the right side and the symbols on the top. Also the desktop size was a little bit changed ...

It's really weird, I hope you can help me!
Thanks in advance!
Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of the info in the link below and a bit of luck!

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-quetzal-nvidia.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue this week.
I have a thinkpad (w530) with a NVIDIA and an intel GPU inside.

so if you have an Nvidia Optimus enabled notebook you could try the following:

- install bumblebee instead of nvidia-current driver https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee
- use nividia-current and enter bios and switch to discrete mode (nvidia chip only)

I switched to discrete mode with the nvidia driver because my mini display port and my vga port are wired to the nvidia chip... it was the easiest way to get an external monitor working. the downside is i couln't get the brightness control working with the nvidia driver...

kr raphael